# text-align: justify doesn't work

Tags: css, justify

Im trying to justify the content of an article but it just wont do......

[image: Text Doesn't Justify]

http://jsfiddle.net/F7dCT/

```
<p style="text-align:justify;" class="default-article-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: Post the code not a screenshot

Comment: there is the code.......

Comment: <p style="text-align:justify;" class="default-article-content">{{article.content}}</p>

Comment: at the bottom of the image

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/F7dCT/1/ seems to work, first one has text-align:justify; seccond one has not ...

Comment: @Gabriel Matusevich Unfortunately, the image and limited amount of code isn't getting it done. Can you provide a link or a JSfiddle?

Comment: the problem is: white-space:pre-wrap; ! see here: http://jsfiddle.net/F7dCT/2/

Comment: I see, but i need to show line breaks, this text is reading a Database of Articles, with breaks, how can I show the breaks AND justify??

Comment: Don't use line breaks, use new paragraphs...that's what they are anyway. Also, don't use `<br>` tag for layout, use margins & padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as we can see in your screen shot your css file has on line 54: `white-space:pre-wrap;`

which is braking your `text-align:justify;`

have a look here I added the classes on those `<p>`tags

```
.justify {
    text-align:justify;
}
.pre-wrap {
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

<p class="justify default-article-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p class="justify pre-wrap default-article-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<p class="default-article-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7dCT/3/